# installed and configured munin server monitoring too: but where is ram usage? and mysql usage?

Tags: munin

I'm at loss, have been trying to dig out something in documentation,but nothing...

It seems mysql ram usage should be part of default Munin package, but they don't show up. Anyone can confirm me this? do I need plugins to add this very important parameter?

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug on ubuntu server: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/munin/+bug/1000678 which prevents memory plugin to function.